# Get country,state and city name in laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

How can I store country,state and city name in database for activity logs

My controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {

      Item::create($request->all());
      DB::table('activities')->insert(
                 array('module' => 1,
                'Description' => Auth::user()->name.'Has created new Item on'.Carbon::now(),
                'name' => Auth::user()->name,
                'IP_address' =>$request->ip()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've build a package [Laravel Cities](https://github.com/igaster/laravel_cities) that might help you. You can seed localy all the cities of any country on the world (provided by geonames.org) and perform any query with the provided Eloquent model. For example you can perform queries like this

```
// Get a Collection of all countries
Geo::getCountries();

// Get the 3 biggest cities of USA
Geo::getCountry('US')
  ->level(Geo::LEVEL_3)
  ->orderBy('population','DESC')
  ->limit(3)
  ->get();
```

An HTTP API is provided along with a vue.js compoment that you can use out of the box.

A single table is used to store the hierarcy so it is very simple to build relations to a Location from another Model.